# PCIe 1x cheap video card for image recognition with existing model

Tags: video-camera, home-security, video-capture, smart-home

When searching for a cheap video card for image recognition all the articles seem to have the AI learning in mind. But that is now what I need.
So the use-case is:
I have a small laptop based server running homeassistant and surveillance recording software. I am running an image recognition software on the images from 2 cameras ones a minute on the CPU. This is working fine but I would like to increase the frequency and probably even number of cameras. All this while not increasing the power usage a lot and in tight budget. The PC has a single PCIe 1x that can be stuffed with a riser.
Is there something that could be just better than CPU or is it a waste of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPU is what you need.

Coral USB accelerator could be used.
[image]

They were originally $79.99, but unfortunately availability suffers and its near impossible to find one that that price.

One amazon user said

> I use it to offload video motion detection from my frigate
> home-assistant instance. It moves the load to the TPU, meaning I can
> run my 7 CCTV cameras at 15 fps. Which previously would not have been
> possible without putting my CPU at 50% load.

Can be found on amazon and at other retailers, but at a wide range of prices.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My investigation lead me to the same conclusion. Already waiting for the shipment.